# Copy file(s) by order using .NET System.IO File.Copy

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm creating a basic file copy operation in windows application. I noticed `System.IO File.Copy` copy files randomly.
Is there a way to control what files should be copied first. For example If we want to copy files starting from smallest to largest file size. Or by Alphabetical order, lets say start copying files with filename [starting from] A to Z, or by numerical order with filename [from] 1 to 100.

I'm using this simple code to copy files from a folder, but this copies files "randomly". See below:

```
Private Sub btnCopy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCopy.Click
    Dim source as string = "c:\copyfiles"
    Dim destination as string = "d:\backup"
    Dim filepath as string = destination & "\"

        For Each filename As String In Directory.GetFiles(source)
            If File.Exists(filename) Then
                Dim dFile As String = String.Empty
                Dim dFilePath As String = String.Empty

                dFile = Path.GetFileName(filename)  'get filenames from source
                dFilePath = filepath & dFile  'concatenate filepath and filename

                File.Copy(filename, dFilePath, True) 'copy files from "c:\copyfiles" folder to destination
            End If

        Next
        MsgBox("Copy Successful", vbOKOnly, "Message")
End Sub
```

Comment: Use LINQ to order the results from `Directory.GetFiles` how you want to order the copying.

Comment: And since `System.IO File.Copy` copies only one file for each call, it cannot do so randomly.

Comment: @crashmstr If its possible copying with smallest to largest file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do want to process them by something other than name (`smallest to largest file size`, or perhaps newest or oldest), then you should use `DirectoryInfo` so you can get at those `FileInfo` properties.

```
' simple ordering by size
Dim dix As New DirectoryInfo(_your_file_path)
For Each f As FileInfo In dix.EnumerateFiles.
               OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Length)
    ' do stuff
Next
```

If you think you might also need filters (ie just copy the files since the last time it ran) then, `EnumerateFiles` rather than `GetFiles()` with some linq will be more efficient. In this case, .NET will evaluate your filter and only return the ones matching your filter(s) rather than all of them for you to exclude manually in code:

```
' process only TXT files in order of size
For Each f As FileInfo In dix.EnumerateFiles.
                Where(Function(w) w.Name.EndsWith(".txt")).
                OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Length)
    ' do stuff
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using foreach in Directory.GetFiles() get the result into a List and sort that list. If you want to sort based on other values, use the FileInfo data block to retrieve the file information and sort based on those values.

With your sorted list, then iterate it using Foreach. The List<> is guaranteed to provide an iterator that returns items in the list in the order they were inserted.

```
 public void GetOrderedFiles()
{
    // Get unsorted list of file names
    List<string> fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strPath);

    List<System.IO.FileInfo> fileInformationList = new List<System.IO.FileInfo>();
    // For each file name, get a full file information block 
    fileNames.ForEach(fileName => fileInformationList.Add(new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName)));
    // Order by CreationTime. Could be any FileInfo data item.
    IOrderedEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> sortedFileInformation = fileInformationList.OrderBy(item => item.CreationTime);

    // Iterate round the sorted collection
    foreach(System.IO.FileInfo fileInformation in sortedFileInformation)
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(fileInformation.FullName, /* Destination file name */)
    }
}
```

Comment: thats a good idea. But it seems its hard for me. If you can provide a simple working example. I will definitely accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sort them first

```
For Each filename As String In Directory.GetFiles(source)
```

Change above line to:

```
Dim filenames() as String
filenames = filenames.OrderBy(Function(f) f.CreationTime) //by time
filenames = filenames.OrderBy(Function(f) f) //alphabetical, not sure of that one
filenames = filenames.OrderBy(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).Length) // by size
    For Each filename As String In filenames
```

Comment: thats a simple solution. I hope this works. thanks buddy

Comment: Give it a try and let me know

Comment: your code above throws an error: "Value of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of String)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'."

Answer (score 1):

Sort by name :

```
For Each filename As String In Directory.GetFiles(source).OrderBy(Function(f) f)
```

Sort by size :

```
For Each filename As String In Directory.GetFiles(source).OrderBy(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).Length)
```