# looping through files in a directory using FileInfo

Tags: vb.net, fileinfo, getfiles

In my application - when users opens a particular form, on page_load I want to be able to go into a specific directory - update some files and then display them to the user. In order to do that I'm using this code....

```
Dim di as New DirectoryInfo ("C:\inbox")
dim ArrFi as FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim fri as FileInfo

if fri.count = 0 then 'If there's no files then no need to stay
  Exit sub
End if
```

Now in this loop below, my goal is do check if a particular file has a specific extension. I did this elsewhere, but I used a STRING as my directory/File name in which case I did this...

```
if stringFileName.EndsWith("TIF") then
  'DO whatever
End if
```

However I am unable to do that here. I'm basically looking to loop through each file and only do something do it when the extension is .TIF but am not sure how to go about it since i'm using FileInfo

```
For each fri in ArrFi
     if Fri.endsWith = "TIF" Then
       'do something
     else
        'Onto next file
     End if
Next Fri
```

Comment: `fri.Name.EndsWith`? You can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: There is also `.Extension` which returns the extension (includes `.` at the start)

Comment: NET will filter then list for you so you dont have to loop anything

Comment: @PLUTONIX - in this case am I able to only .getFiles that have the .tif extension?

Comment: [Copy file(s) by order using System.IO File.Copy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36335878/1070452)   The second, "advanced" answer show how

Comment: @plutonix - my only concern would be that some files might have .tif (lowercase) and some might be saved as .TIF - not sure if this would matter

Comment: You could also use wildcards `di.GetFiles("*.tif")`

Comment: Then use `String.Compare` with the case insensitive flag or `Where(Function(w) w.Name.EndsWith(".txt") OrElse w.Name.EndsWith(".TXT")).`  StringCompare is better to allow for TxT

Comment: Dim lstFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles("YourFilePath", "*.tif")

Comment: @plutonix - thank you

Comment: @Pikoh thank you also

Comment: @Plutonix `EndsWith` also has an overload allowing a `StringComparison` enum so you can ignore case

Comment: Yes, there are actually 3 overloads - forgot about them.

Comment: Thank you all someone post an answer so I can accept